# Is there a way to restrict what branch an action can be run on?

Tags: github-actions

When running a github action manually, I can choose which branch to run it against. This seems like a bad idea for some actions. Especially actions along the lines of `DeployToProduction` - where I only ever want that to be run against the `main` branch.

Is there any way to restrict it to only run against `main` - while still making the action manually-triggered?

An example of a manually-triggered action that I have might look something like this:

```yaml
---
name: DeployToStaging
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs: 
  ...
```

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://github.community/t/limit-branch-for-workflow-dispatch/122099/4?

Comment: A workaround can also be to add a `if` condition at the beginning of each of the workflow jobs to run them only if the branch is the one you want (for example, main).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks for the link. Unfortunately, that never showed up in my searches.

Comment: looks like that link no longer works as it should.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it with a condition:

```
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'

steps:
...
```

in this way the user can see that the action is skipped when selecting a different branch.

Comment: I've been using this solution as well. It isn't ideal imho, b/c it still shows that the workflow tried to run, cluttering up the workflow history. But I think it is the best we have atm.

Comment: This works only if the user doesn't push access. With push access, all the user needs to do is push a branch and update the workflow to be triggered on push.

Comment: Agree with @oyelaking. Tbh this is quite insecure and I could not find a way to limit who can dispatch workflows in repo. If you have a user with push access to repo he can basically create a new branch, modify workflow on his branch and then execute workflow using this custom branch. There is not pull request required, just a branch.

Answer (score 5):

Two alternative ways to check for this with an `if` condition without having to hard-code branch names include:

```
# Only run for the default branch
if: github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch

# Older syntax for GitHub Enterprise Server where ref_name isn't available
if: github.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', github.event.repository.default_branch)
```

and:

```
# Only run for protected branches
if: github.ref_protected == true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a step similar to the following setup to exit the workflow if branch is not master:

```
jobs:
  YOUR_JOB:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Exit if the branch is not master
      run: |
        if [[ "${{ github.ref }}" != "refs/heads/master" ]]; then
          echo "Branch is not master, exiting."
          exit 0
        fi
```