# "Use workflow from" dropdown

Tags: github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions for deployment to production and non-production. GitHub Actions has "Use workflow from" option by default in workflow dispatch. It lists all the branches from my repo. Is there any way I can filter this to certain branches? Specifically for production I would like to see only release/**, master branch in the dropdown.

But I did not find any option to filter it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to restrict what branch an action can be run on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69260199/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-what-branch-an-action-can-be-run-on)

Comment: My question was specific to the UI of github action. I know I can manually check branch ref in workflow yml.

Answer (score 1):

According to github actions documentation, there is no option to filter branches  in the dropdown - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch

But, You can add conditions at job level to filter whether the selected branch from the dropdown is a prod or non-prod branch.

```
  job:
    name: release related
    runs-on: [xx]
    container: xx
    needs: status
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'release/')
    steps:
      - name: Tasks1
        run: echo "Prod"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know this check works. I would like to provide limited branch in the dropdown. If github provide some filtering option to that one it would be really great.